# Change tmux windowlist selection color

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to theme tmux to my liking, and I'm stuck at the windowlist selection.

<kbd>Prefix</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> shows me the windowlist, with selection bar in yellow; anyone know the incantation for modifying that specific bit?

Answer (score 11):

I don't understand why neric's answer is downvoted since it's actually correct.

When you open a windowlist, styles from `mode-style` option are applied to a selected item. [Here is a link to sources.](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/7acc4addb51c711afed3761302c2d3457125445c/window-choose.c#L766) [As you can see](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/f7598b8a267eeab926ed0a934f36595077aab605/options-table.c#L550), the default value is `bg=yellow,fg=black`. You can change those styles in one command:

```
set -wg mode-style bg=red,fg=red
```

- `set` gives a command to set an option;
- `-w` flag tells that this is a window option;
- `-g` flag tells to set the option globally;
- `mode-style` is option's name;
- `bg=red` sets background color of selection;
- `fg=white` sets text color.

Note that `set -wg` is just an alias for `set-window-option -g`.

As for colors, from man page:

> The colour is one of: `black`, `red`, `green`, `yellow`, `blue`, `magenta`, `cyan`, `white`, aixterm bright variants (if supported: `brightred`, `brightgreen`, and so on), `colour0` to `colour255` from the 256-colour set, default, or a hexadecimal RGB string such as `#ffffff`, which chooses the closest match from the default 256-colour set.

You can also specify attributes, for example `bg=red,fg=red,bold`:

> The attributes is either none or a comma-delimited list of one or more of: `bright` (or `bold`), `dim`, `underscore`, `blink`, `reverse`, `hidden`, or `italics`, to turn an attribute on, or an attribute prefixed with `no` to turn one off.

Please note that this option also affects color of text selection in copy mode.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

```
set-window-option -g mode-fg white
set-window-option -g mode-bg red
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set status-utf8 on
set utf8 on

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

set -g status-bg black
set -g status-fg white
```

Comment: it'd help if you explain what these commands do

Comment: set -g status-bg affects the status messagebar, not the windowlist selection bar.